# Is it necessary to migrate repo history in Git-LFS?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm trying to move a large number of files in a Github repo to Git-LFS, but I'm fuzzy on how to use the migrate command. I've tracked all of my files, and pushed the changes to .gitattributes and all the files to the remote branch. But do I need to migrate before the process is complete?

I've done the following:

```
git lfs track "data/ground-truth/*.png" "data/ground-truth/*.tif" "data/ground-truth/*.gt.txt"
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "Tracked ground-truth files with LFS."
git rm --cached "data/ground-truth/*.png" "data/ground-truth/*.tif" "data/ground-truth/*.gt.txt"
git add "data/ground-truth/*.png" "data/ground-truth/*.tif" "data/ground-truth/*.gt.txt"
git commit -m "Converted all tracked files to LFS."
git push
```

A few tutorials I've read say that this is the way to do it, while others say that the process isn't done until I migrate. But I can't find a satisfactory answer as to what migrating is and when I need to do it.

When experimenting, I ran:

```
git lfs migrate import --include="data/ground-truth/*.png,data/ground-truth/*.tif,data/ground-truth/*.gt.txt"
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect, according to git status. But when I add the option --include-ref with my branch, it diverges from the remote branch and I have to force a push. I don't want to do this if it's not necessary.

So is it necessary? Or is it sufficient to perform the initial steps I took to successfully move my files to LFS?

Comment: Your initial steps will place files in future commits in LFS. If you don't do the migration and force push, the remote repo still contains binaries already in it. So if it's necessary depends on your requirements and is highly opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you seem to be looking for, the process may be complete.
If you do not wish to rewrite the Git history so that all past commits manage files under LFS, you do not need anymore steps.

By tracking, adding and committing, you will not touch the history of your repository. Your files are now correctly tracked under LFS.

`git lfs migrate import` is a more automatic tool. It allows you to list the files to be tracked and to rewrite the whole Git history so that all past files are tracked. It is useful if you wish to reduce your repository size. In that case, you will indeed have to force push to share it to all users.